# Flow around a rock in a river: which differential equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differential-equations

I'm a canoist, so I know that when I go with my kayak behind a rock in a river, I feel a current that is *opposite* to the river current.

I'm also I student mathematician, so I would like to see this phenomenon from equations. But I don't know anything about the equations that govern fluid dynamic.

So my problem is: let be $W = \mathbb{R} \times [-2, 2]$ the river and $R = B_1(0)$ the rock (a ball inside the river). Let be $M = W \backslash R$ the river without the rock, i.e. where the water could flow. Let be $\phi: \mathbb{R} \times M \to M$ a function such that $\phi(t, x)$ is the position at time $t$ of the fluid particle that at time $t = 0$ was in position $x$. Let be the water flow from left to right. My question is: what differential equation for $\phi$ I have to solve? And does this equation predict the correct flow behind the rock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest model that fits is [potential flow around a cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow_around_a_circular_cylinder) (or a circle in 2D). This assumes an an inviscid, incompressible fluid with no vorticity, which is too simple to model the backflow. The backflow occurs because of viscosity produces [boundary layer separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_separation).

I think the second simplest model possible would be to solve the steady-state Navier Stokes equations for an incompressible fluid. Then it is just $$(\mathbf{v}\cdot \nabla)\mathbf{v}-\nu\nabla^2\mathbf{v}=-\nabla w$$ $$\nabla\cdot \mathrm{v}=0$$ where $\nu$ is the viscosity and $\nabla w=(\nabla p)/\rho$ is the pressure term (or other forces expressed as hydraulic head). Since you are interested in the 2D case it can also be turned into an equation for [stream functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#Stream_function_for_2D_equations) that leaves out the pressure term.

The [backflow starts at a Reynolds number of about 40](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Emjlai/flows.html). While there are no doubt some analytic solutions for this geometry and low velocities, as you approach higher flow rates/Reynolds numbers they become unstable and you have to rely on [numerical models](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09000).

Answer (score 3):

The equations that describe the flow of fluids like water are the [Navier-Stokes equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations).

These are notoriously intractable. So much so that they are currently the subject of one of [the Millenium prizes in mathematics](http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/navier%E2%80%93stokes-equation). If you're interested in finding out more about this I recommend [Terence Tao's article on the subject](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/03/18/why-global-regularity-for-navier-stokes-is-hard/).

Comment: Which role has the shape of the domain $M$ in these equations?

Comment: @MarcoNervo that would determine the boundary conditions

Comment: While it is true that the full NS equations apply, for this particular case one can likely make use of much simpler restricted versions, e.g. incompressible fluid, laminar flow. I doubt one can go all the way to the irrotational fluid that would turn it into Laplace's equation, but there are simpler models that are used here.

Comment: Your attempt at a mathematical description of the problem leaves out the important fact that the flow is NOT two dimensional, even if you assume the river bed is a horizontal plane and the rock is a vertical cylinder. The surface of the water is an unknown shape which has to be solved as part of the problem. The boundary condition is that the *pressure* at the water surface is constant.

Comment: @alephzero where did I say the flow was two dimensional?

Comment: @JohnRennie You didn't, but the OP did, as I read how it defines the region $W$.

Comment: @JohnRennie Can I ask you to make me see how would you set the _complete_ Cauchy/Dirichlet/PDE problem? Because I am to really understanding..

Comment: @alephzero Why it is not a 2D problem?

Comment: @MarcoNervo because the water can flow up and down as well as sideways and to and fro.